# Batch script with Javaw

Tags: java, batch-file, stdout

I'm trying to do a script in batch to launch many java applications.
I did a loop with a .txt file, I'm trying to start a programm which doesn't open many windows, but just one and print all the outpout of the others. So I did that :

```
start java gateway/gateway %%a
```

Of course th programm is running in background , but how can I redirect the outpout to the actual terminal ?

Thanks

Comment: As `%%a` shows us your posted code is incomplete, so it is quite hard to help you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to redirect programs output back to the Cmd window:

```
Start "" /B java gateway/gateway %%a
```